# rsyslog - Property-based filtering not working

Tags: linux, fedora, iptables, syslog, rsyslog

I almost hate to submit a topic for this, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. I'm running a Federoa 17 server, and I'm attempting to log dropped packets from iptables to a separate log file via rsyslog, but it keeps sending them to /var/log/messages instead.

Snippet from my firewall script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -F

# My accepted rules would be here

iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: "
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: "

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
iptables -L -v
```

The config file that SHOULD be catching the messages from iptables:

```
[root@fc17 ]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf 
:msg, startswith, "iptables: "  /var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

Snippet from my rsyslog.conf file:

```
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#### RULES ####
# I put this in here too to see if it would work; it doesn't
:msg, startswith, "iptables: "  /var/log/iptables.log
& ~

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

I've restarted both iptables and rsyslog multiple times since making the changes, and no matter what, it will only only log dropped packets from iptables to /var/log/messages.

I heard running rsyslog in compatibility mode can cause various problems. Could this be the case here? Here are its run-options on my system:

```
[root@fc17 ]# ps -ef | grep rsyslog
root      3571     1  0 00:59 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -n -c 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `startswith` comparison operator didn't work, because `msg` didn't begin with `iptables:` when I checked my logs:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf 
:msg, startswith, "iptables:"  /var/log/iptables.log
```

However, the `contains` comparison operator worked on my FC18:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf 
:msg, contains, "iptables:"  /var/log/iptables.log
```

Ref: [Rsyslog site](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html)

Comment: Switching to 'contains' instead of 'startswith' did work (it didn't log to /var/log/messages either), and I can definitely leave it this way for now, but is there a way to make 'startswith' work as it should? Is there a way in rsyslog to see how it's parsing its rules from /etc/rsyslog.conf?

Comment: Log line was of the form `Mar 31 14:36:14 localhost kernel: [ 6448.546951] iptables: IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=` and i think that's why `startswith` didnt work. This may help you. http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

Answer (score 1):

you should add the following two line in your "/etc/rsyslogd.conf" in directives part

```
$klogParseKernelTimestamp on
$klogKeepKernelTimestamp off
```

This will remove the kernel timestamp which appears in the begining of every kernel message like "[6448.546951]" in the following log

```
Mar 31 14:36:14 localhost kernel: [ 6448.546951] iptables: IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=
```

Answer (score 0):

2019 solution. Tested with rsyslogd 8.32.0 on Ubuntu18.04.

You can still use `startswith`,

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf 
:msg, startswith, " iptables:"  /var/log/iptables.log
```

by changing the line in `/etc/rsyslogd.conf`

```
module(load="imklog" ParseKernelTimestamp="on" KeepKernelTimestamp="off")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using rsyslogd 5.8.10 over centos 6, my log report show this way:

```
Aug 12 11:50:41 node2 kernel: [10256396.525411] IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:90:c3:05:40:00:24:13:10:8c:00:08:00 SRC=212.237.40.56 DST=37.153.1.29 LEN=45 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=54321 PROTO=UDP SPT=45661 DPT=53413 LEN=25
```

I tried to disabled the timestamp with:

```
$klogParseKernelTimestamp on
$klogKeepKernelTimestamp off
```

But show:

Aug 12 11:50:22 node2 rsyslogd-3003: invalid or yet-unknown config file command - have you forgotten to load a module? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3003 ]

In modules have this:

```
#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability
```

Thank you advance.